# Как осуществить вывод адресной книги в scrolledText?

Tags: python, tkinter

Такая проблема, не знаю команду чтобы вывести из файла в scrolledText.

вот функция вывода и её часть в tkinter

```
    def dump(self):
    for name, addr in self.__records.items():
        print(f'[Имя и адрес] {name}, {addr}')
```

```
name_ins = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(tab3, width=50, height=10, bg="white", fg="black")
name_ins.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=35)
btn = Button(tab3, text="Вывести все адреса", command=ab.dump)
btn.grid(column=1, row=10)
```

Пробовал через name_ins.insert в функции, но выдаёт NameError, пока оставил print (знаю что он не выводит в ScrolledText)

Буду благодарен за помощь, ибо очень нужен вывод в Tkinter

Вот окно tkinter
[image: Выделил вывод, нужно чтобы выводило в консоль]

Comment: посмотрите примеры кода https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-scrolledtext-widget/

Comment: @splash58 Там просто вывод уже заданного текста, мне надо вывод в поле scrolledtext по кнопке как указано в функции

Comment: сделайте маленький воспроизводимый пример

Comment: @splash58, добавил скрин программы, необходимо чтобы выводило не в консоль, а в интерфейс

Answer (score 0):

```
def read_file(path):
    file = open(path, 'r')
    name_ins.configure(tab3, width=50, height=10, bg="white", fg="black", text=file.read())
    file.close
```

Вот так можно наверно. Просто сначала гридануть пустое поле, а после изменить параметры, одним из которых указать текст, который прочитаем из файла. Только осторожно, данная функция должна полностью вывести файл, видеопамяти может не хватить. Хотя TKinter использует C-библиотеку.

Comment: тоже не помогло :(

Comment: @Daniil, какой питон?